# Mysql inner join/ multiple selects in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Hi all!**

I'm scripting a guestbook (personalized for each user). I have one table for users and a different one for the guestbook. Now, the way I'm currently displaying the name of the author of a post is not optimal. I simply have a row in the DB for "fromname" i.e the authors name.
I would like to select the authors name based on the authors ID and matching that to their name in the "users" table.

So... This is my mysql query right now:

```
$sql = " SELECT 
             pid,toid,fromid,message,fromname,name,pdate,flag 
         FROM gbook INNER JOIN users 
         ON id='{$_GET['id']}' 
         WHERE toid='{$_GET['id']}' 
         ORDER BY pdate DESC";
```

I guess I need to like... Select the name on a different condition but in the same query. But I don't know how.

I hope you understand my problem.
Help will be greatly appreciated!

/Jafool

Comment: Can you show us your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `users` table has a column called `username`, the following should do what you want:

```
SELECT 
    pid,
    toid,
    fromid,
    message,
    u.username, 
    name,
    pdate,
    flag 
FROM gbook INNER JOIN users u
  ON id='{$_GET['id']}' 
WHERE toid='{$_GET['id']}' 
ORDER BY pdate DESC"
```

All I did was alias the user table (as u), and refered to u.username instead of the fromname you had before.

Comment: Allright, thanks for your answer!

So I made it to this:

`$sql = "SELECT pid,toid,fromid,message,fromname,u.name,pdate,flag FROM gbook INNER JOIN users u ON id='{$_GET['id']}' WHERE toid='{$_GET['id']}' ORDER BY pdate DESC";`

And when I echo it out like so:
`echo "{$row['fromname']} | {$row['u.name']}";`

The "fromname" works but I get "Notice: Undefined index: u.name in D:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\gb.php on line 129" and u.name does not.

Comment: When you reference it in PHP, you wouldn't use the u. prefix. Try using: `$row['name']`

Comment: I think the problem is resolved!

To share with you all, this is the final result:

         `$sql = "SELECT pid,
        toid,
        fromid,
        message,
        fromname,
        u.name,
        pdate,
        flag FROM gbook INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=fromid WHERE toid='{$_GET['id']}' ORDER BY pdate DESC";`

And to echo it out all I needed was e.g:

    `echo "From: {$row['name']}";`

I'd like to thank every single one of you that posted an answer, because they ALL helped in different ways.

Hopefully this fix won't screw something else up, haha.
Thank you again!

/Jafool

Answer (score 1):

From what I am seeing it looks like you need to link to the users table twice since you have a `fromid` and a `toid`. If you have a users table, why would you have a `fromname` field in the `gbook` table?  Anyway if my assumption is correct then you may be interested in the following query:

```
SELECT g.*, u1.username AS ToUser, u2.username AS FromUser
  FROM gbook AS g
  INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON u1.id = g.toid
  INNER JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.id = g.fromid
WHERE g.toid = '{$_GET['id']}' 
ORDER BY g.pdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding the name in the guestbook table is indeed dirty. Assuming your table structure is something like this:

users( id, name )
gbook( pid, toid, fromid, message, fromname, name, pdate, flag  )

your query is already almost ok. Just change it as follows to select all columns of both tables:

```
$sql = " SELECT *
         FROM gbook g INNER JOIN users u
         ON u.id=g.fromid 
         WHERE toid='{$_GET['id']}' 
         ORDER BY pdate DESC";
```

Then you can display the name with something like

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while( $val = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{ 
  $username = $val["u.name"];
}
```